# Error: Failed to execute child process Failed to execve: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hello I have the following script, I am learning shell scripting:

```
#! /bin/sh
gnome-terminal -- 'cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh'
```

After running this I get the following error:

```
“cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh”: Failed to execve: No such file or directory
```

If I run this command on terminal `cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh` it works just fine. Now I want to write this as a script instead but can't seem to run it.

The goal of this script is very simple. cd to the said folder and then run `./studio.sh`. Extremely basic but I am stuck.

What am I missing? I need help finding errors on this simple script.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use `gnome-terminal`? Instead, just replace line 2 with  `cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to this:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
cd ~/DevSpace/AndroidStudio/arctic_fox/bin/ && ./studio.sh
```

You likely don't need to use `gnome-terminal`.

Your script is a shell script, which uses your system's installation of `sh` as its interpreter. A shell script can run independently from any terminal.

To understand the difference between a shell and a terminal, perhaps consider reading the answers to [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) (though don't be alarmed if the answers are over your head at this stage).